# using a subquery with a having

Tags: sql, sum, subquery, average, having-clause

So the goal is to get a list of customers that have on average ordered more than the total average of all customers.

```
Select customerNumber, customerName, orderNumber, SUM(quantityOrdered)as 'total_qty', ROUND(AVG(quantityOrdered),2) as 'avg'
From customers
join orders using(customerNumber)
join orderdetails using (orderNumber)
Group by customerNumber, OrderNumber
Having ROUND(AVG(quantityOrdered),2) > ROUND(AVG(quantityOrdered),2) IN
        (SELECT ROUND(AVG(quantityOrdered),2) FROM orderdetails)
ORDER BY customerName;
```

My code runs but it doesn't filter the results on the avg quantity ordered column to only show results over the total average of 35.22.

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, you mean:

```
select c.customernumber, c.customername, 
    sum(od.quantity_ordered) as sum_qty,
    round(avg(od.quantity_ordered), 2) as avg_dty
from customers c
join orders o using(customerNumber)
join orderdetails od using (orderNumber)
group by customernumber, customername
having avg(od.quantity_ordered) > (select avg(quantity_ordered) from orderdetails)
```

Rationale:

- you discuss computing the average ordered, but what your query does is compare the average *order detail* quantity per customer; this assumes that the latter is what you want
- then: since you want an average *per customer*, so do not put the order number in the `group by`
- no need for `in` or the-like in the `having` clause: just compare the customer's average against a scalar subquery that computes the overall

Notes:

- don't use single quotes for identifiers (such as column aliases) - they are meant for literal strings
- table aliases make the query easier to write and read; prefixing all columns with the alias of the table they belong to makes the query understandable

Comment: thank you!!!! @gmb You can be my SQL whisperer anytime. I'm just starting to learn and understand sub queries.

Comment: !@gmb if you are so inclined ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949082/joining-sub-queries-and-adding-a-calc-filed-between